# PHP/MySQL Find event within UNIX time span

Tags: php, mysql

i'm hoping to get some help here with a problem I have been struggling with for a long time.

I'm having a MySQL database with events where the starting time of the event is stored in UNIX time. I need to loop thru the next 7 days of the week (today included), from 5AM to 4:59AM to find event that begins within that timespan.

That means, that i need to find all events witch begins from 1418270400 to 1418356799, and then add 1 day to loop to both dates (and not 86400 seconds).

I have been struggling with this for some time, and simply can't get my head around this... Is there a kind person with some more skills with PHP who please could help me?

This is the code i have made to calculate the time periods:

```
$timestamp = time();
$dtNow = new DateTime();
$dtNow->setTimestamp($timestamp);

$beginOfDay = clone $dtNow;

$beginOfDay->setTime(05, 00, 0);

$endOfDay = clone $beginOfDay;
$endOfDay2 = clone $beginOfDay;
$endOfDay->setTime('05, 00, 0');
$endOfDay2->setTime('05, 00, 0');
$endOfDay->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$endOfDay2->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));
$endOfDay->modify('1 second ago');
$endOfDay2->modify('1 second ago');
```

I need to get all events from a MySQL database, that has the timestamp between $beginOfDay and $endOfDay, but are lower then $endOfDay2 ...

Comment: Didn't quite get it. Some PHP codes to explain?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($days as $day) {
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimestamp($starting_timestamp); // OR
    $date->setTime(5);

    $date2 = new DateTime();
    $date2->setTimestamp($ending_timestamp); // OR
    $date2->setTime(4, 59);

    $query = "SELECT event.* from events WHERE timestamp BETWEEN($date->getTimestamp(), $date2->getTimestamp())";
// query stuff or what ever you want to do.
}
```

Just a simple example of something that might work for you, hopefully this helps.

Comment: The problem is, that i need to have the events split into the dates they are happening. So that I have the events that are happening today, then the events happening tomorrow - and so on...

Comment: Store the data in an array for each day.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the mysql [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html):
for example:

```
SELECT * FROM `unixtimestamp` WHERE timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) and timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL +7 DAY))
```

else i think you can use this

```
<?php
$timestamp = time();
$dtNow = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp));

$beginOfDay = clone $dtNow;
$beginOfDay->setTime(05, 00, 0);
echo "begin".$beginOfDay->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 

echo "<br>";

$endOfDay = clone $dtNow;
$endOfDay->setTime(04, 59, 0);
$endOfDay->modify('+1 day');
echo "end".$endOfDay->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
echo "<br>";

$endOfWeek = clone $dtNow;
$endOfWeek->modify('+7 day');
$endOfWeek->setTime(04, 59, 0);

echo "week ".$endOfWeek->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
echo $endOfWeek->format('U');die();
echo "<br>";die();
```